# Web API Route with .Json File Extension

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have an ApiController with the following route ".../api/swagger.json".  Unless I add the next 'add' statement to web.config I get a 404 as IIS is attempting to resolve the address using the StaticFile Handler.

```
<add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*" verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0"/>
```

However, if I add this and you then hit an address that actually doesn't exist (.../api/someGarbage/blah) I get an error 500 -- The user should get a 404 not 500.

What gives?  All this nonsense because i want to use .json in my route name?  There's got to be a fairly simple way to do this.

**Edit**  To be very clear - If I add and configure the ExtentionLessUrlHander as such IIS throws 500 errors for things that should be throwing 404.  This is not the desired default response for all things not found.  You can see from the screen shot that IIS is attempting to execute this nonsense address using the ExtensionlessUrlHandler, fair enough but why can't a get a proper 404 out of it?  Essentially I can service routes with extensions in the paths but I loose 404 as a result..

Comment: Seems logically: from url `...api/someGarbage/blah` the part "someGarbage/blah" have been passed as parameter to the method, where exception was thrown. I think it depend on the code of method and parameter type you are using

Comment: Passed to what? It doesn't exist.  The request doesn't even enter the Asp.net pipeline as my DelegatingHandler is never executed to perform initial route/request checking.

Comment: I know this is old, but I wonder if the 500 you are getting is an issue the CORS headers missing. This is happening to me currently when trying to access routes that have file names, even though the controllers are being hit. The CORS headers are not added. They are added to every other action that doesn't have a route with a filename. I'm not sure if this is a bug in .NET's CORS implementation or what.